# How can i have two organisation-instances with my one live id account

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online

I just want to have a list with organisations after i have logged in with my liveid. Then i select one from these organisations and will be redirected to this organisation. For some weeks i did it so: i created a new test account with my old (used in another CRM online test system) liveid email. And each time after login i had a choice between two organisations. Now it's not possible any more.

How can i have two organisation-insatnces with my one live id account? (goal: DiscoveryService schould return two organisations for my test porposes)

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the URL for one organisation it asks for logon and then delivers that organisation. If you go to the generic page https://crm.dynamics.com and click "customer sign in" then after LiveID sign in you will be prompted for your org.